# enable mysql 5.5 for php

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have mysql 5.5 installed.  when installing php-mysql on centos 5, it failed due to dependency errors.  Seems like the version in the repo conflicts with the MYSQL already installed on the system.

```
# yum install php-mysql
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.0.77-4.el5_5.5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: mysql
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.52-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: mysql conflicts MySQL
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_5.5.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-5 has depsolving problems
  --> mysql conflicts with MySQL-server
Error: mysql conflicts with MySQL-server
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Comment: did you try the suggestions the install made?

Comment: Good, you are using Oracle's official mysql binaries. This is the way to get a well-tested mysql server package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this can be fixed by installing MySQL's MySQL-shared-compat package. This will override Redhat's client library and provide what the other packages need. Then yum won't (hopefully) be tempted to install Redhat's dodgy mysql server.

Comment: I installed the shared-compat package, it didn't help.  I had to install PHP 5.3 from a <a href="http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/">repo here</a>, since php 5.3 does not require php-mysql as a separate package, it works out for me, but how convoluted

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't have a Centos system to look at the packages, but Centos/RHEL have pretty good package dependency trees, and maybe the best thing to do is trust them.  I find it very odd that you have a package "mysql".  [Please see this page](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/yum-groupinstall-mysql-database/) on installing MySQL on Centos.

Restoring from a MySQL dump is a very reliable process.  What I would do in your shoes is do a mysqldump of all your databases, remove *all* mysql packages, then try installing php-mysql
and let it bring in what it thinks are the right packages.  Then you can restore your data from the dump you made.

Comment: nice suggestion on yum group, I will try that next time.  dump the data out and reinstall mysql is too much of a time consuming task for me so I installed php 5.3 instead